# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two classes that there is a relationship @ OneToMany (Pay and Split) the code below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagamento")
public class Pagamento implements Serializable { //Class Pay

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="idpagamento")
private int id;
...
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="idconta")
private Divida coddivida;
```

and below class Split

```
@Entity
@Table(name="divida")
public class Divida implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idconta")
private int id;
...
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER,                   mappedBy="coddivida",        targetEntity = Pagamento.class)
private List<Pagamento> pagamento;
```

And I search through the data code below:

```
 public List<Divida> getDividas(){
    return getCleanListOfObjects(Divida.class,"from Divida divida");
}
```

And I'm trying to display in a datatable is as below:

```
<p:dataTable id="paneluser" value="#{dividaFaces.listofDivida}" var="divida" selection="#{dividaFaces.selectedDivida}"
                     rowKey="#{divida.id}" selectionMode="sigle" emptyMessage="Não existe Dívida" paginator="true" rows="10">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Panel de Dívidas Cadastradas
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Descricão">
                #{divida.descricao}
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="pagar" headerText="Tela de Pagamento">
                <p:commandButton value="Pagar">
                    <p:ajax oncomplete="pagetela.show()" update="telapgamento"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                Financé v#{sistema.VERSION}
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
```

But it is giving the error below:

```
Hibernate: 
 /* 
from
Divida divida */ select
    divida0_.idconta as idconta0_,
    divida0_.datadeinicio as datadein2_0_,
    divida0_.descricaodespesa as descrica3_0_,
    divida0_.empresa as empresa0_,
    divida0_.exercicio as exercicio0_,
    divida0_.observacao as observacao0_,
    divida0_.operacaobancaria as operacao7_0_,
    divida0_.parcela as parcela0_,
    divida0_.tipolancamento as tipolanc9_0_,
    divida0_.vencimento as vencimento0_ 
from
    divida divida0_
Lista de Dividas: []
Hibernate: 
 /* 
from
Divida divida */ select
    divida0_.idconta as idconta0_,
    divida0_.datadeinicio as datadein2_0_,
    divida0_.descricaodespesa as descrica3_0_,
    divida0_.empresa as empresa0_,
    divida0_.exercicio as exercicio0_,
    divida0_.observacao as observacao0_,
    divida0_.operacaobancaria as operacao7_0_,
    divida0_.parcela as parcela0_,
    divida0_.tipolancamento as tipolanc9_0_,
    divida0_.vencimento as vencimento0_ 
    from
    divida divida0_
    Mar 26, 2013 8:34:31 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
    SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/menu/principal.xhtml]
    java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.finance.model.Divida cannot be cast to java.util.List
at    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findSelectedRowKeys(DataTable.java:977)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:624)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:234)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:196)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please update your question in order to show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your managed bean. Looks like the problem is in `selection="#{dividaFaces.selectedDivida}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using selectionMode="sigle". Please notice the missing 'n' in single. The exception you are encoutering here has nothing to do with Hibernate.

Comment: This looks more like a typo while writing the question.

Comment: This is what I thought at first time, but then, when examining the question, I am pretty sure, this is the issue, unless 'listofDivida' isn't itself a list.

Comment: Thanks Every body with code like this:

<!-- language-all: lang-html -->

<p:dataTable id="paneluser" value="#{dividaFaces.listofDivida}" var="divida" selection="#{dividaFaces.selectedDivida}"
                         emptyMessage="Não existe Dívida" paginator="true" rows="10">

it´s works.

Comment: @MiguelCPJava sorry to say, but this answer didn't helped you at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Please notice that, as I said in my answer, the real issue, is with wrong typo "sigle" instead of "single" and for something, Primefaces considered it as multiple selection mode. And from that you can see that ClassCastException, not being able to cast Divida to List

Comment: If you read last comment from MiguelCPJava in your answer, he doesn't use the `selectionMode` anymore.

Comment: and this is the only thing that he changed, which means that the error was from selectionMode="sigle" that he originally wrote and that was my remark

Comment: Exactly @LaabidiRaissi only changed selectionMode="single", so it will be that change to another mode it´s will works, I going to try this idea.